# Laravel/Blade - Extend same template multiple times on same page

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

So there must be a simple way around this... On my site there are multiple modals, depending on the page. I've created a modal template that these can all extend. However, the last modal I include on the page ends up 'taking over' the rest of them, and so all my modals end up with the same sections from that last include. How can I make it so that each extension is unique to the file from which it extends?

Example of what's happening:

```
//template.blade.php
<htmls and stuff>
    @yield('section_1')
    @yield('section_2')
</htmls and stuff>

//Modal 1
@extends('template')
@section('section_1')
    Some words
@stop
@section('section_2')
    More words
@stop

//Modal 2
@extends('template')
@section('section_1')
    Rabbit
@stop
@section('section_2')
    Stew
@stop
```

Instead of two unique modals being loaded, I end up with two modals full of Rabbit Stew.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally would use includes in this instance, unless you've got markup in your sections. If it's just text you could do something like this:

```
//template.blade.php
<htmls and stuff>
    {{ $section1 }}
    {{ $section2 }}
</htmls and stuff>

//Modal 1
@include('template', ['section1' => 'Some words', 'section2' => 'More words'])

//Modal 2
@include('template', ['section1' => 'Rabbit', 'section2' => 'Stew'])
```

Comment: Mmm yeah I've learned about passing strings like that. I am in fact including markup however - basically each modal has different elements and some involve sections that others don't. Hoping there is some way of doing it, I'm using bootstrap modal and there's they're a bit weighty as far as markup goes.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure then, I'm sure someone here will know. You could potentially do something like this `@include('template', ['section1' => View::make('modals.section1', $data), 'section2' => View::make('modals.section2', $data)])` However it's a little messy

Comment: ```@overwrite``` in stead of ```@endsection``` will solve the problem better

Answer (score 10):

Try using the `@overwrite` command instead of `@endsection`

Example:

```
@section('stuff')
     Stuff goes here...
@overwrite
```

Source: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1058#issuecomment-17194530

Comment: I think this solution didn't exist when the question was first asked, but this solves the problem perfectly and still allows complicated markup.

Comment: This is the better answer as it will solve a broader range of issues than the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I really wanted to use Blade templates too, but ended up using php includes, **even with basic html markup**.

```
//Modal 1
@include('layout.template', array(
'section1'         => 
'<h1>Modal 1</h1><p><b>Some</b> words</p>',

'section2'         => 
'<p>Some <u>words</u></p>'

))
//Modal 2
@include('layout.template', array(
'section1'         => 
'<h1>Modal 2</h1><p><b>Some</b> words</p>',

'section2'         => 
'<p>Some <u>words</u></p>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com"></a>'

))
```

**The markup all works just fine, including links.** Where I ran into trouble was when I wanted to use includes *inside* the include arrays, which I understand is not possible. That is why I wanted to use Blade Templates.